# jQuery: adding element with dynamically calculated top property

Tags: jquery

In order to perform some animations I need to add a second image, identical to the one I already have in my document, with the value of `top` property equal to the height of the image.

Right now I do:

```
$("#blur").after("<img src='someimg.jpg' id='above' >");
var t = -($("#blur").height());
$("#above").animate({top: t}, 1);
```

But it's rather ugly - one can see the moment when new element is created and then moved to the right position.

Is there any way to place the second `<IMG>` with automatically calculated `top` walue?

My goal is to have two identical images stacked one over the another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, just set the 'top' CSS style property before adding the new image to the DOM:

```
 var t = $('#blur').height();
 $('<img src="someimg.jpg" id="above">')
 .css('top', -t)
 .insertAfter('#blur');
```

In practice though, it's better to set the `position` attribute to `absolute`, since otherwise that `top` attribute will be relative to the element's default position, instead of relative to the origin of the first image.

```
 var t = $('#blur').height();
 $('<img src="someimg.jpg" id="above">')
 .css({
    position:'absolute',
    top: 0, left: 0       // should be implicit anyway
 })
 .insertAfter('#blur');
```

p.s. use single quotes around your strings and HTML snippets, so that you can use the correct double-quote character for HTML attributes.

EDIT - for a more general solution (see http://jsfiddle.net/bE7TH/)

```
function overlay(selector, new_id) {
    $(selector)
    .clone()
    .removeAttr('id')
    .attr('id', new_id)
    .css({
        position: 'absolute', left: 0, top: 0
    })
    .insertAfter(selector);
}
```

I think the original element will have to have a `position` property of `fixed` or `absolute` for this to work properly, and you may also need to account for any margin or padding too.

Comment: Great! Works fine. Can I get the `src` for new image in similar way?

Comment: what do you mean by 'get' the src ?

Comment: ah, you mean you want the two elements to be identical, without knowing in advance what the first image was?

Comment: Thanks! Basing on your code I used something like that: `$("#blur").clone().removeAttr('id').attr('id', 'above').css('top', t).insertAfter('#blur');`